# In Visual Studio how to access the source control history window programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio Extension. I need to access the Source Control's History window to check what history items are selected or not.

I've tried several methods including the `findWindowPane()` method and the `activeWindow` object, but none of them worked. (I didn't know all the parameters for `findWindowPane()` and the `activeWindow` doesn't have any info about specific tool window data)

**Update**

So I've checked the solution on this page:  [Show item history windows with TFS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267888/show-item-history-windows-with-tfs-sdk)
Unfortunately, when I'm trying to get the *type* of the *history window*, the result is null.

```
Type _dialogHistoryType;

Assembly tfsAssembly = typeof(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.LocalPathLinkBox).Assembly;
_dialogHistoryType = tfsAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.DialogHistory");
var historyWindow = package.FindToolWindow(_dialogHistoryType, 0, false);
```

**My main goal is to get the selected history item's id from the history window during runtime.**

Any suggestion, how to get the type?

Comment: is it the same issue as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061180/how-to-get-the-selected-items-on-source-control-history-window-when-creating-a-v?, sorry for I didn't get Email update for that case. For this issue, maybe you could use certain tool to help you find the specific class or UT control, and then it would help you write the custom code like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267888/show-item-history-windows-with-tfs-sdk, this is just about the changeset history: http://www.aymanzaza.com/2012/01/15/get-latest-changeset-history-from-version-control/

Comment: Yes they are the same, thanks for the answer, i will check it out! :)